# Filtering with the Kendo UI ComboBox in the ASP.NET MVC on array of numbers

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem to use filtering in the Kendo UI *ComboBox* with the list of integers.  I use list of integers as a *DataSource*, Filter of type *StartsWith* and *ServerFiltering(false)*.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Placeholder("Jahr")
      .IgnoreCase(true)
      .Name("planungsZeiten")
      .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetPlanungsZeiten", "Reweco"))
                                  .ServerFiltering(false)))

public JsonResult GetPlanungsZeiten()
{
    using (var repo = new ANECON_PDATAEntities())
    {
        return Json(repo.PlanungsZeiten.Select(j => j.Jahr).OrderByDescending(j => j).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

As I type in the *ComboBox*, *JavaScript* exception is thrown:

*Object doesn't support property or method  'toLowerCase'*

[image]

[image]

This happens because the type number don't support the method *toLower*.

The version I using is 2013.1.514 but the same behavior is on latest version 2014 Q1 SP1 (2014.1.416) as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/akalcik/Fv8S5/1/

I already tried to set *.IgnoreCase(true)* but it make no difference. Do I something wrong or is it the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startwith is not a valid filter for integer type. You should either use integer filters (equal, greater than, etc.), or change the type of your underlying source integer field to string to apply string filters.